# ZStack alignment not centered when in GeometryReader?

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader, zstack

I have the following view:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center)) {
                                
                    Text("TEST TEXT")
                
            }.background(Color.red)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Renders this:

[image]

I want views in the ZStack to be centered, and that only works if I remove the `GeometryReader`, like so:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center)) {
            
            Text("TEST TEXT")
            
        }.background(Color.red)
    }
    
}
```

Renders this:

[image]

How can I use the `GeometryReader` and still have content in the ZStack be centered like shown in the last render picture above? Why is GeometryReader messing with the ZStack content alignment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GeometryReader's alignment keeps changing - see [GeometryReader Discrepancies with Previous OS Versions](https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-bug/). To get the normal behavior, I usually just add `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)`.

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack { /// no need for the custom Alignment
                Text("TEST TEXT")
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) /// here!
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Text is centered]

Comment: that works. thank you. I'll mark it as the answer once it allows me.

Comment: This didn't work for me. iOs 15.5 and xCode 13.4

Answer (score 0):

For now(Xcode 13.4, iOS 15.5), use 'position' modifier.

```
struct TestingGeometryReader: View {
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        Text("TEST TEXT")
            .position(x: geo.frame(in: .local).midX, y: geo.frame(in: .local).midY)
    }                
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution than high vote answer, you only need set padding with `ZStack`

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Text("TEST TEXT")
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            // Set padding here
            .padding(.vertical, geometry.size.height / 2)
            .padding(.horizontal, geometry.size.width / 2)
        }
    }
}
```